# Change filter programatically in administrator article manager

Tags: administrator, article-manager

I'm trying to link my admin component to the administrator article manager, and when the list of articles appear, I want it to show only the Unpublished articles.

Is there any way to change the filter programatically, like a GET parameter or something like that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes that's possible, try this URL:

```
/administrator/index.php?option=com_content&filter[published]=0
```

This works with every other filter as well. Just look up the **name** attribute of the filter HTML element.